# Can't find Neo4jImport.bat

Tags: neo4j, r-neo4j

I just installed `Neo4j 2.2 Milestone 1 Release` on a Windows 64-bit machine and I am unable to locate the file `Neo3jImport.bat`.

I want to play around with the [feature](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/re03.html) described here.  Until now, I have been playing around with the `RNeo4J` package.  It has helped the learning curve quite a bit, but now that I am goint beyond toy datasets, importing data using the package is painful.

With that said, I can't seem to locate the file/utility that seemingly makes importing larger datasets a breeze.  I was expecting to see the file at `C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\bin`.

I imagine this is a really basic question, but I am somewhat stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you download the executable? I think it may be missing on there for some reason. Should be on the zip version though - http://info.neotechnology.com/download-thanks.html?edition=enterprise&release=2.2.0-M02&flavour=windows&packaging=exe&architecture=x64&_ga=1.92518685.1231895929.1406902291

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the exclusion but the binary installation misses also Neo4jShell and other command line scripts as is is intended for a UI only user.

Please use the ZIP download from neo4j.com/download as Mark suggested.